wrong dynamic DNS resolution following upgrade to ubuntu 24.04, help!
I upgraded a laptop from Ubuntu 22.04 to 24.04.
I now receive a wrong IP for my DDNS...
The weird thing is that everything is fine on the other machines on my LAN.
I use DDNS names mainly for sshing, nextcloud and similar.
Internet connection is ok, I can ran ping hostname without problems.
The DDNS service (dynu) has been set up on my router.
This is the nslookup output from the "faulty" laptop, no change if I leave the 8.8.8.8 off:
nslookup XXXX.dynu.net 8.8.8.8
Server:     8.8.8.8
Address:    8.8.8.8#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   XXXX.dynu.net
Address: 94.140.14.35

Again, if I ran nslookup on other machines I get the right IP (which is different from the one above).
The /etc/hosts and /etc/resolv.conf files:
cat /etc/hosts
127.0.0.1   localhost
127.0.1.1   franchi-hp

# The following lines are desirable for IPv6 capable hosts
::1     ip6-localhost ip6-loopback
fe00::0 ip6-localnet
ff00::0 ip6-mcastprefix
ff02::1 ip6-allnodes
ff02::2 ip6-allrouters

cat /etc/resolv/.conf
nameserver 127.0.0.53
options edns0 trust-ad
search .

The status of the systemd-resolved service:
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/systemd-resolved.service; enabled;>
     Active: active (running) since Sun 2024-08-04 07:23:55 CEST; 37min ago
       Docs: man:systemd-resolved.service(8)
             man:org.freedesktop.resolve1(5)
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-network->
             https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/systemd/writing-resolver>
   Main PID: 1031 (systemd-resolve)
     Status: "Processing requests..."
      Tasks: 1 (limit: 18914)
     Memory: 4.4M (peak: 5.9M)
        CPU: 458ms
     CGroup: /system.slice/systemd-resolved.service
             └─1031 /usr/lib/systemd/systemd-resolved

ago 04 07:23:55 franchi-hp systemd[1]: Starting systemd-resolved.service - Netw>
ago 04 07:23:55 franchi-hp systemd-resolved[1031]: Positive Trust Anchors:
ago 04 07:23:55 franchi-hp systemd-resolved[1031]: . IN DS 20326 8 2 e06d44b80b>
ago 04 07:23:55 franchi-hp systemd-resolved[1031]: Negative trust anchors: home>
ago 04 07:23:55 franchi-hp systemd-resolved[1031]: Using system hostname 'franc>
ago 04 07:23:55 franchi-hp systemd[1]: Started systemd-resolved.service - Netwo>
ago 04 07:24:01 franchi-hp systemd-resolved[1031]: wlp0s20f3: Bus client set de>
ago 04 07:24:01 franchi-hp systemd-resolved[1031]: wlp0s20f3: Bus client set DN>

FURTHERMORE, I tried to put the "wrong IP" retrieved by nslookup in google-chrome (http://94.140.14.35/): on all my laptops and PC, I get the page Access blocked by AdGuard DNS: Parental control...
Yet, it didn't help removing all parental-control options from my router and browser. Besides, I never installed Adguard on the laptop. I get the same page on other PCs in my LAN.
I have no idea how to further narrow the problem, of course I can add other details if someone can help.
Thanks

Just to be clear, on this one machine you get a different IP address for XXXX.dynu.net than you do on the other machines? What happens if you leave the 8.8.8.8 off from the nslookup command? i.e. use your system's DNS resolution?

Correct, different IP on the other machines. No change removing 8.8.8.8.

Anything in /etc/hosts?

I think nslookup bypasses /etc/hosts

I added /etc/hosts and other details anyway. http://94.140.14.35/ (the IP I get by nslookup) is blocked by a misteriuos (for me) Adguard DNS. Thanks for the help.

since /etc/resolv.conf points to a local dns server, you likely are using systemd-resolve so it may also help to include the real file at /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf

It might be the other way around: maybe your other machines are still using a (somehwere) cached DNS entry to resolve the host, while the new updated one has it "right", perhaps because of some sort of cache invalidatiion / purge happened during the update. Failing what user10489 said (find the culprit in /run/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf), I'd try to resolve the name using an online service and check the domain's DNS records.

Yes, this is all about finding the culprit.  Resolve it two ways that get different answers, figure out which answer is right, and then track down where the other one got the wrong answer.  Keep doing that until you find something you can kick (to clear cache) or delete from the path (like the AdGuard DNS).

So I checked and added /usr/systemd/resolve/resolv.conf, it is different from /etc/resolv.conf but both files are like the ones on other machines (e.g. fedora 40, another ubuntu  24.04). Shall I delete /etc/resolv.conf and see what happen? I think the "wrong IP" is the one from the upgraded laptop, all the others have got the right ddns association. I checked the ddns log on dynu website, it redirects to my public IP. I have been trying to track the adguard dns "cache" or path, but no idea about it, possibly it is embedded with browser or os?

No, don't  delete resolv.conf, that will just break it more.

Silly question...have you tried rebooting?  I mean, there are always was of flushing the cache, but that is the easiest...

Yes, no change unfortunately. I tried to purge and then reinstall systemd-resolved, no luck with that. really weird for me, everything is fine on all my devices including another ubuntu 24.04 laptop.

Reinstalling ironically does not affect cache.  If rebooting doesn't fix it, then it is possible something upstream (external to your machine) is filtering dns.  This is likely if nslookup 8.8.8.8 is giving the wrong answer.
